# Mac StoreKit "An unknown error has occured" on purchase

Tags: macos, app-store, in-app-purchase, storekit, appstore-sandbox

Im trying to test my in app purchases in mac osx application as always.
But something happened today and i cant test a single in app.

First i add my payment to SKPaymentQueue,
When it asks - i enter the test user account,
Then i press yes in confirmation dialog, 
And after that i just get strange dialog box saying "**An unknown error has occurred**" with buttons "cancel" and "retry".

When i press "retry" - literally nothing happens. 
No absolutely no logs in system console, no changing in SKPaymentTransaction status.. nothing.

Transaction status stays in **SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing** state until i press "cancel" in that strange dialog.
And only after that i get **SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed** (because it is canclled)

I have tried the other mac, i tried other application (even one that is live and was tested fine like 5 days ago), i tried to create new test user, regenerate app id, provisions and etc.
I have deleted system caches, NetworkInterfaces.plist and did other stuff that i found in google as possible workaround.

What do i do?

Answer (score 0):

For you, this is probably not true, but I'll write for others. In iTunes Connect will likely have InApp-Purchase does not fill in the localization data